# How to eliminate repeat code in a for-loop?

Tags: java, dry

I have implemented two member functions in the same class:

```
  private static void getRequiredTag(Context context) throws IOException
  {
    //repeated begin
    for (Record record : context.getContext().readCacheTable("subscribe")) {
      String traceId = record.get("trace_id").toString();
      if (traceSet.contains(traceId) == false)
        continue;
      String tagId = record.get("tag_id").toString();
      try {
        Integer.parseInt(tagId);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        context.getCounter("Error", "tag_id not a number").increment(1);
        continue;
      }
      //repeated end
      tagSet.add(tagId);
    }
  }

  private static void addTagToTraceId(Context context) throws IOException
  {
    //repeated begin
    for (Record record : context.getContext().readCacheTable("subscribe")) {
      String traceId = record.get("trace_id").toString();
      if (traceSet.contains(traceId) == false)
        continue;
      String tagId = record.get("tag_id").toString();
      try {
        Integer.parseInt(tagId);
      } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        context.getCounter("Error", "tag_id not a number").increment(1);
        continue;
      }
      //repeated end
      Vector<String> ret = traceListMap.get(tagId);
      if (ret == null) {
        ret = new Vector<String>();
      }
      ret.add(traceId);
      traceListMap.put(tagId, ret);
    }    
  }
```

I will call that two member functions in another two member functions(so I can't merge them into one function):

```
private static void A()
{
  getRequiredTag()
}
private static void B()
{
  getRequiredTag()
  addTagToTraceId()
}
```

`tagSet` is `java.util.Set` and `traceListMap` is `java.util.Map`.

I know `DRY principle` and I really want to eliminate the repeat code, so I come to this code:

```
  private static void getTraceIdAndTagIdFromRecord(Record record, String traceId, String tagId) throws IOException
  {
    traceId = record.get("trace_id").toString();
    tagId = record.get("tag_id").toString();
  }

  private static boolean checkTagIdIsNumber(String tagId)
  {
    try {
      Integer.parseInt(tagId);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  private static void getRequiredTag(Context context) throws IOException
  {
    String traceId = null, tagId = null;
    for (Record record : context.getContext().readCacheTable("subscribe")) {
      getTraceIdAndTagIdFromRecord(record, traceId, tagId);
      if (traceSet.contains(traceId) == false)
        continue;
      if (!checkTagIdIsNumber(tagId))
      {
        context.getCounter("Error", "tag_id not a number").increment(1);
        continue;
      }
      tagSet.add(tagId);
    }
  }

  private static void addTagToTraceId(Context context) throws IOException
  {
    String traceId = null, tagId = null;
    for (Record record : context.getContext().readCacheTable("subscribe")) {
      getTraceIdAndTagIdFromRecord(record, traceId, tagId);
      if (traceSet.contains(traceId) == false)
        continue;
      if (!checkTagIdIsNumber(tagId))
      {
        context.getCounter("Error", "tag_id not a number").increment(1);
        continue;
      }
      Vector<String> ret = traceListMap.get(tagId);
      if (ret == null) {
        ret = new Vector<String>();
      }
      ret.add(traceId);
      traceListMap.put(tagId, ret);
    }    
  }
```

It seems I got an new repeat... I have no idea to eliminate repeat in that case, could anybody give me some advice?

update 2015-5-13 21:15:12:

Some guys gives a boolean argument to eliminate repeat, but I know
`Robert C. Martin's Clean Code Tip #12: Eliminate Boolean Arguments.`(you can google it for more details).

Could you gives some comment about that?

Comment: I think this question should have been posted in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So, you are worrying about DRY; but you are not worried about having all static methods (which will make it very hard to write proper unit tests for all of this)?

Comment: Why all static method is hard to write unit tests? could you give me more hint about that? @Jägermeister

Comment: The static methods them self might be easy to test. But consider classes that make use of those static methods. Normally, you use frameworks like EasyMock to create "mocks" of objects; thereby you can control the "input" to a class under test ... but when your class under test is using static methods/objects in other classes; but EasyMock or Mokito can't mock "static". So you have to turn to PowerMock; which will hamper  other tools (like coverage measurements). Long story short: **static** can be seen as "abnormal" in a object oriented design; only use it when you know what you are doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parts that changes requires the values of `String tagId` and `String traceId` so we will start by *extracting an interface* that takes those parameters:

```
public static class PerformingInterface {
     void accept(String tagId, String traceId);
}
```

Then extract the common parts into this method:

```
  private static void doSomething(Context context, PerformingInterface perform) throws IOException
  {
    String traceId = null, tagId = null;
    for (Record record : context.getContext().readCacheTable("subscribe")) {
      getTraceIdAndTagIdFromRecord(record, traceId, tagId);
      if (traceSet.contains(traceId) == false)
        continue;
      if (!checkTagIdIsNumber(tagId))
      {
        context.getCounter("Error", "tag_id not a number").increment(1);
        continue;
      }
      perform.accept(tagId, traceId);
    }    
  }
```

Then call this method in two different ways:

```
private static void getRequiredTag(Context context) throws IOException {
    doSomething(context, new PerformingInterface() {
         @Override public void accept(String tagId, String traceId) {
              tagSet.add(tagId);
         }
    });
}

private static void addTagToTraceId(Context context) throws IOException {
    doSomething(context, new PerformingInterface() {
         @Override public void accept(String tagId, String traceId) {
             Vector<String> ret = traceListMap.get(tagId);
             if (ret == null) {
                 ret = new Vector<String>();
             }
             ret.add(traceId);
             traceListMap.put(tagId, ret);
         }
    });
}
```

Note that I am using lambdas here, which is a Java 8 feature (`BiConsumer` is also a functional interface defined in Java 8), but it is entirely possible to accomplish the same thing in Java 7 and less, it just requires some more verbose code.

Some other issues with your code:

- Way too many things is `static`
- The `Vector` class is old, it is more recommended to use `ArrayList` (if you need synchronization, wrap it in `Collections.synchronizedList`)
- Always use braces, even for one-liners

Comment: Unfortunately, I works on `Java 6`... Could you give me some example about verbose code you mentioned?

Comment: alright, I'll write up some example code for Java 6

Comment: @Sayakiss It is possible to do it in Java 6 too, it's just a lot more verbose.

Comment: Really thanks... I know it's the way of functional language thinks about problem but I just don't know how to change my mind into a functional way. You r example will help me a lot.

Comment: @Sayakiss I have updated the code to show you how it is done. As biziclop notes, this can be seen as a usage of the Strategy pattern.

Comment: @Sayakiss That's a whole new question, if you do a search on SO, you'll find plenty of good answers.

Answer (score 1):

tagId seems to be always null in your second attempt.

Nevertheless, one approach would be to extract the code that collects tagIds (this seems to be the same in both methods) into its own method. Then, in each of the two methods just iterate over the collection of returned tagIds and do different operations on them.

```
for (String tagId : getTagIds(context)) {
// do method specific logic
}
```

EDIT

Now I noticed that you also use traceId in the second method. The principle remains the same, just collect Records in a separate method and iterate over them in the two methods (by taking tagId and traceId from records).

Solution with lambdas is the most elegant one, but without them it involves creation of separate interface and two anonymous classes which is too verbose for this use case (honestly, here I would rather go with a boolean argument than with a strategy without lambdas).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stream (haven't tested):

```
private static Stream<Record> validRecords(Context context) throws IOException {
    return context.getContext().readCacheTable("subscribe").stream()
        .filter(r -> {
            if (!traceSet.contains(traceId(r))) {
                return false;
            }
            try {
                Integer.parseInt(tagId(r));
                return true;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                context.getCounter("Error", "tag_id not a number").increment(1);
                return false;
            }
        });
}

private static String traceId(Record record) {
    return record.get("trace_id").toString();
}

private static String tagId(Record record) {
    return record.get("tag_id").toString();
}
```

Then could do just:

```
private static void getRequiredTag(Context context) throws IOException {
    validRecords(context).map(r -> tagId(r)).forEach(tagSet::add);
}

private static void addTagToTraceId(Context context) throws IOException {
    validRecords(context).forEach(r -> {
        String tagId = tagId(r);
        Vector<String> ret = traceListMap.get(tagId);
        if (ret == null) {
            ret = new Vector<String>();
        }
        ret.add(traceId(r));
        traceListMap.put(tagId, ret);
    });
}
```

Comment: The OP said in a comment to my answer that Java 6 is being used, so Streams does not seem to be an option unfortunately.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yeah, just noticed that too.

Answer (score -1):

Try this approach

```
private static void imYourNewMethod(Context context,Boolean isAddTag){
        String traceId = null, tagId = null;
        for (Record record : context.getContext().readCacheTable("subscribe")) {
          getTraceIdAndTagIdFromRecord(record, traceId, tagId);
          if (traceSet.contains(traceId) == false)
            continue;
          if (!checkTagIdIsNumber(tagId))
          {
            context.getCounter("Error", "tag_id not a number").increment(1);
            continue;
          }
        if(isAddTag){
            Vector<String> ret = traceListMap.get(tagId);
              if (ret == null) {
                ret = new Vector<String>();
              }
          ret.add(traceId);
          traceListMap.put(tagId, ret);
        }else{
            tagSet.add(tagId);
        }
    }
```

call this method and pass one more parameter boolean true if you want to add otherwise false to get it.

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @Sayakiss I updated my answer with required example hope it will work for you, Please note that I have not tested it.

Comment: Alternating the functionality of a method by adding a boolean parameter is a horrible practice.

Comment: @Sayakiss If you dont have any issue to merge your two methods in single one , the above answer will best suit for you as less code is always good for development.

Comment: Less code is not always good for development. Especially when that code is not clear. Using a `boolean` switch for this functionality only makes the underlying functionality. A method should only do one thing, this method does two different things, depending on the value of the boolean.